# Printing from the iPhone

Tags: iphone, printing

Are any libraries available that facilitate printing files (TXT, RTF, etc.) from the iPhone/iPod Touch?

Comment: What are you looking to print to?  A printer on the local WiFi network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has iOS 4.2+, you can use AirPrint, which is part of the iOS SDK.  You can also detect at runtime if it's available with code like this:

```
 Class printControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInteractionController");
 if (printControllerClass) {
   [self setupCanPrintUI];
 } else {
   [self setupCannotPrintUI];
 }
```

That way your app can still work on previous iOS versions, although it won't be able to print from them.

If you draw a long string (such as the entire contents of a text file) into a graphics context and put that into a PDF data format, you can print it.

Check out [Apple's docs on UIPrintInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [this blog post](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=115) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In [this](http://tuvix.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/PortingfromCocoa/PortingfromCocoa.html) document it's said, printing is not supported, but there are apps in the app store supporting it. As far as I can see, all those need a special client on another computer which is connected to a printer.